# Error in Databinding a property to a label in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I am to build basic application in wpf; I am not able to display student name ("Alexa") in  the MainView. Here are my code details:

I have a **Student.cs** class in **Model**  as shown

```
    namespace Client.Model
{
    class Student:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name ="Alexa";
       

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    } }
```

And MainViewModel.cs is

```
  class MainViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
      

        public Student Student
        {
            get { return _student; }
            set {
                if (_student != value)
                {
                    _student = value;

                }
                OnPropertyChanged("_student");
                            }
        }       

    }
```

In my MainView, I am trying to display the student name as

```
 <Label FontStyle="Italic" >Student Name is:</Label>
<Label FontStyle="Italic" Content="{Binding Student.Name}" ></Label>
```

Also I have set

`this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();` in MainView.cs

What am I missing?

Comment: you are missing _name = value in your Name Property btw. Also I suggest you to make the Student class public, since you are binding in to your View

Comment: You may have forgotten to initialize the `_student` field or the `Student` property. Besides that, the Student property setter must call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Student));`, and the Name property is missing `_name = value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the `Student` property somewhere:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Student _student = new Student(); //<--

    public Student Student
    {
        get { return _student; }
        set
        {
            if (_student != value)
            {
                _student = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Student));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that you should use the `nameof` operator to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the *property* in the `MainViewModel` class.